# There is a sudden increase in loss in my machine training. Is there any specific reason and how it could be addressed?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have been training my dataset using a neural network as follows based on a dataset of a stock market index.  But all of a sudden after running like over 60 times and the loss suddenly upsurge.  Has anyone encountered that and what could be the possible reasons for the increase of loss?

```html
 tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5,
                      strides=1, padding="causal",
                      activation="relu",
                      input_shape=x_train_single.shape[-2:]),
  tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)),
  tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 100)
```

```html
Epoch 64/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 420ms/step - loss: 0.2506 - mae: 0.5902 - lr: 1.8197e-05
Epoch 65/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 417ms/step - loss: 0.2608 - mae: 0.6035 - lr: 1.9055e-05
Epoch 66/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 418ms/step - loss: 0.2683 - mae: 0.6048 - lr: 1.9953e-05
Epoch 67/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 417ms/step - loss: 0.7993 - mae: 1.2234 - lr: 2.0893e-05
Epoch 68/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 420ms/step - loss: 1.8172 - mae: 2.2769 - lr: 2.1878e-05
Epoch 69/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 417ms/step - loss: 5.6831 - mae: 6.1442 - lr: 2.2909e-05
Epoch 70/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 423ms/step - loss: 4.5647 - mae: 5.0645 - lr: 2.3988e-05
Epoch 71/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 418ms/step - loss: 0.9771 - mae: 1.4475 - lr: 2.5119e-05
Epoch 72/100
50/50 [==============================] - 21s 419ms/step - loss: 0.1717 - mae: 0.4792 - lr: 2.6303e-05
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIvBr.png)

Answer (score 2):

LSTMs do sometimes suffer from exploding gradients. I had this problem as well. Some steps that might help you are the following.

1. Change your batch size. Generally the idea is the bigger the faster the convergence. Might help, it wasn't really helpful in my case.
2. Change your learning rate or use the callbacks API of tensorflow for learning decay.
3. If you are willing to change your architecture, you can try the GRU network. It's said that it generally fixes the problem of exploding gradients that LSTMs may have. However, in certain use cases they may underperform. Good thing is that you can still be using a bidirectional neural network with GRU, so the changes in your code would be (probably) minimal.
4. The one thing that did the trick for me was Normalization of my data. At first I thought I didn't really needed this, since I was working with vehicular speeds, but I was blown away by the accuracy after doing this. So I would suggest to look into data normalization/standardization.
5. An other technique that could help is batch normalization. I have not tried this on my own, but it is said to be useful in this use case.
6. Use another optimizer.

If this happens in the beginning of your training, it might be that a new feature has been fed to the network. So, the network can't approximate the given input with its current weights and the loss is large. This would be expected and neccessary for the training.